# How to reproduce the sound of Dizzy's muted trumpet in early bebop jazz recordings?

Tags: jazz, trumpet, mute

How can I reproduce the muted trumpet sound of Dizzy Gillespie's that can be heard in many of the early bebop recordings together with Charlie Parker?

I believe he was using a cup mute, but is the material and/or other properties of the mute relevant? What do I need to emulate this sound?

Here are some listening examples with the sound I'm asking about:
* [Bloomdido](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MCGweQ8Oso) (Melody plus solo @1:26)
* [Mohawk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0ttQZ-QaNE) (Melody plus solo @1:48)
* [Groovin' High](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1JUd0NFBIc) (Melody plus solo at @1:34)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bobby Shew names a mute made in Sweden (how ironic, given your name) in the following words:

> There is a company in Sweden that makes the Dizzy Gillespie model
>   mutes which, when you can find them, are worth purchasing although
>   very expensive. The cup in this set is made of a white plastic and
>   separates into two pieces, one of which looks like a straight mute and
>   which could be used as one, and another piece which is similar to a
>   plunger which snaps over the end of the straight to form a cup. It has
>   a surprisingly good sound for being plastic. It lacks the hard,
>   brittle quality which makes the metal mute undesirable,

http://www.bobbyshew.com/clinics/Mutes.htm

People at thetrumpetherald seem to think the brand name is Ullven:
http://www.trumpetherald.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=396166&sid=54cff5da7758ec3fd70599160a0101bf

They don't seem to be in business anymore, and I am not even sure that that is the model Gillespie actually uses.

Bobby Shew seems to like the Humes & Berg MIC-A-MUTE,

> which is the same as the basic cup with a rubber ring around the edge
>   of the cup to control the seal or space near the bell of the horn.
>   This mute also has a soft fuzzy material covering the inside of the
>   cup area, the purpose of which is to soften the "wooden" hardness of
>   the sound of the regular cup.

I believe this could be the best you can aim for?